# как отправить из кода php в базу данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql

я хочу  отправить результат $k из кода кода php в базу данных  mysql, подскажите как правильно написать код чтобы он отправлялся.

```
<form method="get" action="insert.php">


        1. He was an HONEST man. <br>
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad1" Value="true" >  A) liar    </INPUT>
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad1" Value="false">  B) good    </INPUT>

    <br>

    2. The climate of Great Britain is MILD.

    <br>

    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad2"  Value="true"  >A) difficult</INPUT>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad2"  Value="false" >B) strong</INPUT> 
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad2"  Value="false" >C) severe</INPUT>


      <input  type="submit"  Value="отправка"/> <br>

       </form>
```

---

//insert.php

```
<?php
      $k=0;

for ($i=1;$i<11;$i++)
    {
    if (isset($_GET["rad".$i]))
        {
        if ($_GET["rad".$i]=="true")
            $k++;
    }
}
?>


<form method="get" action="update.php">

        <insert name="not" value="$k">// так неправильно


<?php echo $k; ?>  //-хочу отправить  "$k" в базу данных 


    <h1> Правленые ответы</h1>


<input  type="submit" name="button1" Value="отправка"> 

                </form>
```

---

//update.php  //отправка в базу данных.

```
<?php


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
          if (!$con)
                  {
                  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                  }

mysql_select_db("basses", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO Table(not)VALUES('$_POST[not]')";


    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
               {
               die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
               }


echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
    <p>1. He was an HONEST man.</p>
    <label>A) liar
        <input type="radio" name="rad1" value="true" />
    </label>
    <label>B) good
        <input type="radio" name="rad1" value="false" />
    </label>
    <p>2. The climate of Great Britain is MILD.</p>
    <label>A) difficult
        <input type="radio" name="rad2"  value="true" />
    </label>
    <label>B) strong
        <input type="radio" name="rad2"  value="false"/>
    </label>
    <label>C) severe
        <input type="radio" name="rad2"  value="false"/>
    </label>
    <p><input  type="submit"  value="отправка"/></p>
</form>
```

Как работать с формами читайте [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php);

Как обрабатывать данные перед занесением в бд читайте [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/143035/);

```
if($_POST){
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "db");

    /* проверка соединения */
    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        printf("error connection: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $not = $mysqli->real_escape_string($not);

    /* Создание таблицы не возвращает результирующего набора */
    if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Table (not) VALUES ('$not')") === TRUE) {
        echo "1 record added";
    }
}
```

Как взаимодействовать с бд читайте [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php), а после [тут](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo);

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: За ссылки вы правы, надо подумать, спасибо. А давать в  данном случае человеку простой кусок раб.кода - считайте отщипнуть от его мозга.

Comment: Никто не заставляет Вас, давая готовый ответ и/или код, удалять ссылки.